# Reading XLSB file with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading xlsb file with below code, but its printing as text, I want to get headers, data values for each cell to set to java objects. Which classes should I use. Thanks in advance.

```
    File file = null;
    OPCPackage pkg = null;      
    XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor ext = null;

        try {           

        file = Paths.get("C:/Users/U574564/Ref/source/Q4_GL_Assignment v1.xlsb").toFile();          
        pkg = OPCPackage.open(file,PackageAccess.READ);
        ZipSecureFile.setMaxTextSize(110485766);
        ext = new XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor(pkg);  
         System.out.println(ext.getText());

        }   catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Did you try [XSSFBSheetHandler](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/binary/XSSFBSheetHandler.html)? Example given in [source code for XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/extractor/XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor.java)