# Reading xlsb files throws error - java poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, illegalaccessexception, xlsb

I'm attempting to use Apache POI and getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader.pkg from class org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFBReader
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFBReader.getXSSFBStylesTable(XSSFBReader.java:78)
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.extractor.XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor.getText(XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor.java:122)
>       at xlsbpar.XlsbPar.main(XlsbPar.java:38)

Here's my code:

```
XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor ext = null;
try {
    ext = new XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\abc.xlsb");
    System.out.println(ext.getText());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Don't mix jars between versions! You need to have all your POI jars on the same version for it to work

Comment: Exactly! I excluded the previous version of apache poi but i forgot remove the apache tika library which I was not using at all. The problem resolved immediately after removing the reference of Apache Tikka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor` (need `poi-ooxml-x.y.jar` as the external library, where x.y represents the version) as the error itself states:

> **tried to access field org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader.pkg**
>   from class **org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFBReader**.

```
XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor ext = null;
try {
    ext = new XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\abc.xlsb");
    System.out.println(ext.getText());

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Also, you may like to check [this question on reading xlsb file using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900342/reading-xlsb-file-with-apache-poi) where OP has used almost the similar code with slight addition to achieve the desired result.

Comment: i need to parse the file with xlsb format if I use XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor it will give null for the statement      sop(ext.getText())  Even after changing the ext to XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor, the error remains the same

Comment: @saran - Check this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900342/reading-xlsb-file-with-apache-poi ; OP was able to successfully read data. You should give a try once instead! In case of any further query, feel free to ask.

Comment: I begin writing using that code snippet for which i received the same error My aim is to read and access the data in the xlsb file which i am trying to do using apache poi 3.16 but unfortunately i am receiving this error

Comment: The issue is resolved when I tried the snippet in a separate java file.
Though, I am facing the following error in my project (NoSuchFieldError) java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RAW_XML_FILE_HEADER    Thanks Bro!

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet in the following works perfectly for the XLSB parsing 
[Reading XLSB file with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900342/reading-xlsb-file-with-apache-poi)
which @AM_I_Helpful was suggesting